# Is there any way to get rid of fields while running quser command via powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am running the quser command from one of my powershell script and that displays

PS C:\Users\Arun> quser

```
USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
Arun         console             1  Active    1+01:58  01/06/2016 14:01
```

Is there any way to restrict the no.of fields in the display of the quser command.I wanted to attach this content into an email body.So wanted it to short.

Case 2:

Output with multiple rows looks like below:

---

```
USERNAME     SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
Arun         console             1  Active    1+01:58  01/06/2016 14:01
ABC                              1  DISC      1+01:58  01/06/2016 14:01
DEF                              1  Active    1+01:58  01/06/2016 14:01
GHI         console              1  DISC      1+01:58  01/06/2016 14:01
IJK                              1  DISC      1+01:58  01/06/2016 14:01
```

Tried the modified code provided in one of the solutions.
But however the data shifts left when there is a blank value for sessionname.

```
USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
 abc12367                                  2  Disc         2:08  5/20/2016 4:55 PM
 def12367                                  3  Disc      4+03:55  6/9/2016 11:13 AM
>ghi12367               rdp-tcp#3          4  Active          .  6/13/2016 10:00 AM
 jkl12367                                  5  Disc           10  6/10/2016 3:54 PM
 abc12367                                  7  Disc      2+23:56  5/19/2016 12:15 PM
 mno12367                                  8  Disc      3+22:07  6/9/2016 4:52 PM
 pqr12367              rdp-tcp#1           9  Active         12  6/9/2016 7:55 PM
 stu12367              rdp-tcp#2           10  Active          .  6/13/2016 10:35 AM
 vwx12367                                  11  Disc         4:21  6/13/2016 10:38 AM
```

code used to print the variable values continuous:

```
quser | select -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object { 
    $current = $_ -split '\s+'
    $i = 0;
    $username = $current[$i++].Trim('>')
    if ($current.Length -eq 7) 
    {
        $sessionname = $current[$i++] 
    }
    else
    {
        $sessionname = $null
    }
    $1=$current[$i++]
    $2=$current[$i++]
    $3=$current[$i++]
    $4=$current[$i++]
    $5=$current[$i++]
    $6=$current[$i++]
    $7=$current[$i++]


write-host $1
write-host $2
write-host $3
write-host $4
write-host $5
write-host $6
write-host $7

}
```

Could you please help me in resolving the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could parse it yourself. You have to skip the first entry, iterate over it and split the string using `\s+`. Now you can access the data you want using an array index, here an example for the first two columns:

```
quser | select -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object { 
    $current = $_ -split '\s+'
    $username = $current[0].Trim('>')
    $sessionname = $current[1]
}
```

---

**Answer to your comment:**

```
quser | select -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object { 
    $current = $_.Trim() -split '\s{2,}'
    $i = 0;
    $username = $current[$i++].Trim('>')
    if ($current.Length -eq 6) # entry containing session name
    {
        $sessionname = $current[$i++]    
    }
    else
    {
        $sessionname = $null
    }

    $id = $current[$i++]
    $state = $current[$i++]
    $idleTime = $current[$i++]
    $LogonTime = $current[$i++]

    return [PSCustomObject]@{
        Username = $username
        Sessionname = $sessionname
        Id = $id
        State = $state
        IdleTime = $idleTime
        LogonTime = $LogonTime
    } 
}
```

Comment: This helped me a lot. A small query,when i run this on my server ,there are some rows which has the second field as blank and some rows have the fields with values (for ex: session name ).But as the split is made on the one or more space ,the rows that are having the blank in the field get the field 3 as field2 value.Any suggestion on how to get rid of that issue?

Comment: Just check for the count of `$current` within an if statement and skip the assignment of the second property in that case.

Comment: we cant actually skip the property as the second field has values for some of the rows. :(

Comment: just edit your question and add an example, I will try to help you.

Comment: Added the output sample

Comment: I edited my answer as well. Im also creating a `PSCustomObject` there to  have an object with properties you can use in PowerShell. If you want to work with them, you have to assign the whole statement to a variable, e. g. `$parsedOutput = quser | ....`

Comment: BrandI ,I have tried the above code and saved the variables into $1 to $7 and printed them using a writehost $1 to $7.However this seems to be working fine for few lines at some point the variables assignment shift s to the left giving the $6 value as $5( for example).Could you please guide me in resolving this..something minute stuff is being missed from my side.

Comment: BrandI ,I have pasted my code in the original query.Appended to the last along with the data and all.

Comment: I edited my answer again, just try the last piece of code

Comment: BrandI thanks for your answer,But the piece of code is now skipping the first and second fields and generating the output without username and the sessionname.

Comment: Can you type `quser > output.txt` in cmd and send me the file? Its hard to reproduce without the exact output

Comment: BrandI i am not sure if we have a facility to attach the output here.But the quser output is exactly the one which i have posted yesterday.

Comment: hey @Martin BrandI, Thanks alot for your help,i just realized i was using wrong variables and it worked fine now.Above code is perfect and awesome.Really appreciate for your turnaround on this.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$quser = (quser) -replace '\s{2,}', ',' | ConvertFrom-Csv

$quser | select username, 'logon time'

# yields:
# USERNAME          LOGON TIME
# --------          ----------
# >anthony.stringer 6/2/2016 7:36 AM
```

or to convert to html

```
$quser | select username, 'logon time' | ConvertTo-Html | Set-Content C:\temp\test.html

start C:\temp\test.html
```

Comment: Nice one. I always forget about `ConvertFrom-Csv` :)

Comment: Thanks alot Anthony.will contverto-HTML give the output to HTML view ,as when i tried earlier it used to give me the number count of lines instead of the data.Any suggestion ?

Comment: This will only work if all the columns has values. In my case `SESSIONNAME` is empty so this solution won't always work.